# Imagemagick use-trimbox doesn't work at all

Tags: linux, pdf, image-processing, imagemagick

I'm desparately trying to convert PDF to JPG by Imagemagick (convert command) preserving trimbox. 
I run following command (convert only first page).

```
convert -verbose -define pdf:use-trimbox=true "test_org.pdf[0]" cropped.jpg
```

Here is an output. Looks like imagemagick doesn't pass use-trimbox parameter to the ghostscript. May that be a reason? As at the moment converted image is mediabox size, not trimbox. Version of ImageMagick is 6.0.7, ghostscript GPL Ghostscript 8.64.

```
convert: **"gs" -q -dBATCH -dSAFER -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dNOPAUSE -dAlignToPixels=0 "-sDEVICE=bmpsep8" -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 "-g652x935" "-r72x72" -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 "-sOutputFile=/tmp/magick-XXgTtZZG" "-f/tmp/magick-XXs4Kjq2" "-ftest_org.pdf".**
/tmp/magick-XXgTtZZG[0] BMP 652x935 PseudoClass 256c 2.3mb 0.050u 0:01
/tmp/magick-XXgTtZZG[1] BMP 652x935 PseudoClass 256c 2.3mb 0.040u 0:01
/tmp/magick-XXgTtZZG[2] BMP 652x935 PseudoClass 256c 2.3mb 0.020u 0:01
/tmp/magick-XXgTtZZG[3] BMP 652x935 PseudoClass 256c 2.3mb 0.010u 0:01
test_org.pdf PDF 652x935 652x935+0+0 DirectClass 2.3mb 0.040u 0:01
test_org.pdf PDF 652x935 652x935+0+0 DirectClass 2.3mb 0.040u 0:01
test_org.pdf=>cropped.jpg PDF 652x935 652x935+0+0 DirectClass 202kb 0.120u 0:01
```

Answer (score 1):

You possibly have too old ImageMagick. Works fine in my case.

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.6.0-4 2010-11-16 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

`-define pdf:use-trimbox=true` makes `convert` invoke `gs` with `-dUseTrimBox` option, which I don't see in output provided by you. Consider updating ImageMagick.

Answer (score 0):

Your ImageMagick 6.0.7 is more than 6 years old (dozens of releases back). Current is 6.7.0-9.
Your Ghostscript 8.64 is also more than 2 years old already (5 releases back). Current is 9.02.

My recommendation is to upgrade.

On my (Windows) system I have IM 6.7.0-8 and GS 9.02. Running `-define pdf:use-trimbox=true` works fine here and translates to a Ghostscript commandline parameter of `-dUseTrimBox=true`.

**However (and this is important!):** one should take into account, that for many practical example PDFs out there, `TrimBox` is undefined, or explicitely set to the same values as `MediaBox`. Both have the same effect: a `-dUseTrimBox=true` will not make any difference in the output to a `-dUseTrimBox=false`.